# Is it possible to sync an Outlook 365 calendar with Outlook.com?

Tags: sync, calendar, outlook.com, microsoft-outlook-365

I currently use Thunderbird as my email client, but would like to switch to Outlook in order to have a more flexible calendar experience (specifically, being able to add/edit/delete events on either my phone or desktop and have those changes persist).  Is there a way to sync a calendar on Outlook 365 with Outlook.com WITHOUT having to manually save the desktop calendar and upload it?

In other words, can I set it up so that a change on the desktop version of Outlook will automatically be pushed to the online version and vice versa?  If it's possible, how is it done?

EDIT:
This is a consumer version of Microsoft 365.  The email host... doesn't matter?  I have four email accounts going through the desktop version of Outlook 365 currently - one from my ISP, three from Gmail.  I have 0 intention of using Outlook.com for email.  I just want to integrate my desktop calendar with it, if possible.

To be clear, I've never used Outlook.com before... My hope is that I can just have an online calendar (like, say, Google Calendar) that I can both access from desktop Outlook (and, by access, I mean able to add/edit/delete events) and my iPhone.

Comment: Who is the email account host? Is this a business Office 365 account? Is this a 3rd party account? Please provide more details and use the EDIT button to add this info to the question itself.

Comment: Added more detail in an edit

Comment: Outlook.com supports Microsoft Exchange.  So you would have to synchronize the same Outlook.com account with Outlook 365 and the Outlook application on your phone. Of course Google has a mobile Calendar application you could also use. The built-in Calendar application on iOS supports Google Calendar

Comment: Ok, as this is specifically a question about the web app Outlook.com we will need to get this question moved over to our web apps sister site.

Comment: Also, the email host DOES matter. The email host must support whatever protocols Outlook.com supports in order for anything to work.